# base.html isnt accessing the static files in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am encountering an error with accessing my static files when i make different request from the nav of my website . it basically accessing the static files when i load the index page `www.xxxx.com/static_url`(from my settings.py) but when i make a request from `www.xxxx.com/path` it goes to `www.xxxx.com/path/static_url` which is 404 i have nothing there. 
how can i maintain this ?

in the base.html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

header.html

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'files:documents' %}">name</a></li>
```

Comment: What have you defined as your `STATIC_URL` setting?

Comment: For consistency have you tried using the same `{% static ... %}` method in header.html?

Comment: @solarissmoke STATIC_URL = 'frontend/static/' so when i make a request from the index page the path shows as www.xxxx.com/frontend/static/css/main.css but when i make a request from www.xxxx.com/path my wesbite tries to go to www.xxxx.com/path/frontend/static/css/main.css

Comment: you mean you want me to call my static files in the header file ? i thought my css files have to be in the header tag !

Comment: You need to change `STATIC_URL` to `/frontend/static/` - note the slash at the beginning. What you currently have is a relative URL which is why your paths fail.